# Can I safely Install Visual Studio 2010 AFTER Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2012

I know traditionally its best to install programs in the order they were 'born' as that's generally going to avoid more problems.

Are there any known chronological dependencies between these two programs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It works on my machine.

I just did it a day or so ago and had no problems. I was surprised at how smoothly it went, so if that's any indication of the usual, it should be a breeze.

Visual Studio is pretty good about installing to a particular directory, with the exception of support components (which are detected as already-installed and skipped). When installing 10 after 11, only 10 itself and a runtime or two were needed. Both 10 and 11 have been working perfectly since, including 11's support for compiling projects as 10 (to support XP, which was why I installed both).

It does get a little bit messier with installing 9 (2008), but you can typically install that after 10 and use the back-compiling. I have no idea what happens if you install 11, then 10, then 9 (it could work).

Comment: Thankfully I wont need to go back as far as 9! I was amazed at how quickly 11 installed on my clean Win8 SSD box. Wanted to avoid putting 10 on until I really need it (for work) hence my install order!

Comment: Just installed **VS 2008** after having **VS 2012** for a few month on my Windows 8 PC. Everything seems to work fine in VS 2012, even ReSharper and other Add-ins still work like normal.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2012 broke 2010 for me, but I don't know if it would break the other way. Certainly, don't do it on your production environment.

*Workaround* : freely downloadable Windows SDK has the vc10 compilers and toolchain, and you can use it when compiling from VS2012. Just select appriopriate platform toolset in project options.

Comment: I've already tried 2012 on top of 2010 which worked fine (There are some caveats in the README of things that break but they are rather obscure stuff like if you are using x64 compilers on certain OS)

Comment: For me it broke the vc10 linker. It's just you *can't* really be sure. You can try it on a virtual machine or some other PC, but if it's your only development computer, it will always be risky.

Comment: This looked like a great option, only it failed to install on my W8 machine with a setup error "can't install a DLL already there", and there wasn't enough info in the log file for me to figure out what was going on. :(